# Stream files from FTP to DLNA

Tags: ftp, dlna

We have a FTP server here in the dorm, and I would like to reach the files on it over DLNA with my TV. I am looking for a software that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run a DLNA server such as `minidlna` on the machine with the files you wish to access via DLNA. The FTP server is not necessary.

Comment: But the machine with the files isn't mine, it is a public FTP server here in the dorm network. They won't install DLNA server if I ask them.

Comment: You should still be able to access media from a file server once it's mounted on your Ubuntu box using miniDLNA to serve them to your TV.

Answer (score -1):

the app DLNAserver does perfectly the job. You acces the ftp server and the app translates the files on the ftp to DLNA and makes them accessable on any DLNA device, so also your TV. I have an ancient HD recorder with a hugh harddisk (2 terra) and ftp function, so I installed on my old smartphone from 10 years ago the app and it serves permanently as my dlna server and all my ftp files are everywhere available all the time on dlna. My kids love it to watch there cartoons. At the same time I gave my old phone a second useful life!